# How evil is $_REQUEST and what are some acceptable Band-Aid countermeasures?

Tags: php, security, xss

I've come across a couple of popular PHP-related answers recently that suggested using the superglobal `$_REQUEST`, which I think of as code smell, because it reminds me of `register_globals`.

Can you provide a good explanation/evidence of why `$_REQUEST` is bad practice? I'll throw out a couple of examples I've dug up, and would love more information/perspective on both theoretical attack vectors and real-world exploits, as well as suggestions of reasonable steps the sysadmin can take to reduce risk (short of rewriting the app ... or, do we *need* to go to management and insist on a rewrite?).

**Example vulnerabilities:** Default `GPC` array merge-order means that COOKIE values override GET and POST, so `$_REQUEST` can be used for XSS and HTTP attacks. PHP lets cookie vars overwrite the superglobal arrays. First 10 slides of [this talk](http://www.slideshare.net/ZendCon/lesser-known-security-problems-in-php-applications-presentation) give examples (whole talk is great). [phpMyAdmin exploit](http://www.hardened-php.net/advisory_072006.130.html) example of CSRF attack.

**Example countermeasures:** Reconfigure `$_REQUEST` array merge-order from  `GPC` to `CGP` so GET/POST overwrite COOKIE, not the other way around. Use [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) to block overwrite of superglobals.

(Also, wouldn't be asking if I thought my question was a dupe, but happily the overwhelming SO answer to ["When and why should $_REQUEST be used instead of $_GET / $_POST / $_COOKIE?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107683/when-and-why-should-request-be-used-instead-of-get-post-cookie) was "Never.")

Answer (score 6):

Just treat it as it is: a method to get data from the user.  It has to be sanitised and validated, so why should you care if it came in the form of a POST, a GET or a cookie?  They all come from the user, so saying 'they can be spoofed!' is superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

$_REQUEST is a evil as $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. While i think there are valid scenarios for using $_REQUEST but there is one good reason not using $_REQUEST and label it as "bad practice".

The main reason using $_REQUEST is that parameter can get transferred in $_POST or $_GET. By accessing $_REQUEST you don't have to check both $_GET and $_POST it the value is set. The problem is that the ini setting [gpc_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.gpc-order) can change the behavior how $_REQUEST is build. This setting may differ from server to server and you script may change the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

`$_REQUEST` is problematic because it ignores the difference between URL (`$_GET`) and request body (`$_POST`). A HTTP-GET request should be without side-effects, while a HTTP-POST may have side-effects and thus can't be cached. Throwing these quite different data sources into one bucket, calls for applications that are un-[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)-ful, which is to say bad applications.

Comment: note: both GET and POST requests can get `$_GET` and `$_POST` data.  There's no relation between the HTTP method and the specific superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

Its vulnerable to anything passed on the URL.  Thus if a form contained a hidden field with the "userid" that was submitted with the form, although in theory the user can't edit it, there is nothing stopping them change the value if keen enough.

If you just want to get the value off the request, thats fine, but you need to be aware that it may very well be spoofed, so you need to act accordingly, and certainly not use it for secure param/value data.

Comment: You could also spoof the form post or the cookies.  There's nothing special about POST of COOKIE that makes it harder to spoof then GET.

Comment: There is one thing though. GET variables can used as part of an CSRF-attack. Only allowing POST or COOKIE for certain things, makes this kind of attack harder.