# Is there any way of handling events in php

Tags: php, events

Is there any way to handle events in php, I'm looking for a way to handle event's like posting a form.
Thanks,
Sreejith

Comment: PHP runs on server side. It can't handle client side UI events.

Comment: This question is vague and confusing.

Comment: @Darin, To the server mostly to index.php

@Pekka, I was thinking of events like in ASP

@Dan, Sorry for that, I was looking for a way similar to ASP events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting a form is not really an event: the page is just called (that's the only event you'll get as far as i know), but you can check for certain values to be present in `$_GET`, `$_POST` or the combined `$_REQUEST`, and act on them.

Comment: Yes, I was actually looking to figure out a way if any event occurs when the server recieves the POST

Comment: No real event, the server just receives a request for you page, but there is something in the `$_POST` variable.. and you can check for that ofcourse in your file. It's just your basic file-loading. As if you'd load the file without posting, or as if you're doing a reload. But then with extra data in those pre-mentioned vars.

Answer (score 4):

The reason (probably) why people are confused by "PHP" + "events" is that there is no such thing as *events* in PHP technically speaking. PHP scripts receive "*requests*", and you can discern requests via the `$_POST` and `$_GET` global variables. (There is also the `$_REQUEST` variable, but it's use is... sometimes [questionable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258625/how-evil-is-request-and-what-are-some-acceptable-band-aid-countermeasures).)

Anyhow, there is no concept of "form submission" in PHP either; this is a client-side concept. Simply because you can perform a POST or a GET request to a PHP script with or without going through a `form` element and, from a PHP point of view, you cannot tell the difference.

Also, since a PHP request is single threaded (to the extend of my knowledge at least), your "event" will probably look like this (for a POST request) :

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    // we suppose that the submit button was pressed and the form was sent
    // we suppose also that other data is also present in $_POST
    //
    // handle form post event here
}
```