# how to parse $_REQUEST?

Tags: php

here i am checking for and getting part of the request, (the ids). i also print out the entire request:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ids'])){
    $amount = sizeof($_REQUEST['ids']);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "<br>$amount invitations Successfully Sent";
}
```

this is how  the entire $_REQUEST prints out:

```
Array
(
    [mfs_typeahead_req_form_4cf74f96db3688507476560] => Start Typing a Name
    [ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 510149460
        )
    [fbs_258181898823] => \"access_token=258181898823|2.q_qb_yoReO0_xc4H8PxKRQ__.3600.1291280400-100000664203700|LqtGr_OiJTASGmek61awxmxfvFk&expires=1291280400&secret=85eTEELZj8lkV82V_PwRSA__&session_key=2.q_qb_yoReO0_xc4H8PxKRQ__.3600.1291280400-100000664203700&sig=d4cc0e4c0992ea29c0adfd60dc27185b&uid=100000664203700\"
)
```

i need to parse the part at the end: &uid=100000664203700, specifically '100000664203700'

Comment: You can do it with preg_match http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Do not use `$_REQUEST` here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368329/php-using-get-post-instead-of-request

Answer (score 1):

```
$queryString = $_REQUEST["fbs_258181898823"];
$output = array();
parse_str($queryString, $output);
print $output["uid"];
```

Comment: thanks, but fbs_258181898823 isnt set by me its dynamically set by fb. how can i access it without using the key?

Comment: Is there a pattern to this? Does the name always start with fbs_?

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) will break up things that look like a query string. I recommend you pass an array as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)—it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `\"` (using a combination of `preg_replace` and `stripslashes`) at the beginning and the end, then use [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(^"|"$)/', '', stripslashes($_REQUEST['fbs_258181898823']));
parse_str($str, $data);
$uid = $data['uid'];
```