# In which condition we use $_REQUEST variable instead of $_GET or $_POST variable

Tags: php, environment-variables

In which condition we can use $_REQUEST variable instead of $_GET or $_POST variable. I confused about when use $_request variable because this can be used for both uses of $_get and $_Post variable . So please me help me..

Thank you in advance...

Comment: DUPLICATE - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368329/php-using-get-post-instead-of-request?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post?rq=1

Comment: When you ask a question like this, if you'll look in the bottom - right quadrant of the page, you will see **Related** questions that probably have the answer.

Comment: yes dude !.. i apreciate with you all .. But i couldn't understand it .. that's why asking.. ! and i hope you will undestand me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: Always use `$_GET` or `$_POST`. `$_REQUEST` is synonymous with either but detracts from being a diligent, strict coder.

Answer (score 1):

$_REQUEST, by default, contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

But it's only a default, which depends on variables_order ; and not sure you want to work with cookies.

I would not use $_REQUEST,I choose $_GET or $_POST depending on application

You should use $_GET when someone is requesting data from your application.
And you should use $_POST when someone is pushing (inserting or updating ; or deleting) data to your application.

Answer (score 0):

$_REQUEST is not that bad but what if you are getting data from $_COOKIE and hackers send that with $_GET?? your saved value in cookie will be of no value then. SO, always always use $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE respectively..