# Undefined index when using $_request

Tags: php, android

I got an error when i use $_Request . this is my code

```
$lat2=$_REQUEST['lat'];
$lng2=$_REQUEST['lng'];

$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into markers_awal values('','$lat2','$lng2') ",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo"hi";
}
```

this is my error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: lat in C:\xampp\htdocs\MUF_Surabaya\Rute\insert_android.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: lng in C:\xampp\htdocs\MUF_Surabaya\Rute\insert_android.php on line 11

hi{"code":1}
```

can anybody explain to me,, thnk you

Comment: how you are passing values to insert_android.php ? using get or post

Comment: It means that `$_REQUEST`doesn't have en element with key `lat`. Try var_dump($_REQUEST) to see what the array looks like.

Comment: @Anish : `GET` and `POST` both will be accepted in `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Show of your html form..

Comment: @Ranjith agreed. just wanted to check whether they are aware of that :)

Comment: @Ranjith I use $lat2=(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) ? $_REQUEST['lat'] : '');
$lng2=(isset($_REQUEST['lng']) ? $_REQUEST['lng'] : ''); but my query is being 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for values with `isset()` or `empty()`

```
$lat2=(isset($_REQUEST['lat']) ? $_REQUEST['lat'] : '');
$lng2=(isset($_REQUEST['lng']) ? $_REQUEST['lng'] : '');
```

Good to get values with what method you are using `$_GET` or `$_POST` 
Why :- [Why should I use $_GET and $_POST instead of $_REQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368329/why-should-i-use-get-and-post-instead-of-request)

Comment: Even `$_REQUEST` also accepts both the method. Is there any reason to preferable any of them?

Comment: @Ranjith may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368329/why-should-i-use-get-and-post-instead-of-request

Comment: @user3233176 try to echo your both variables what they have values looks like no values geted

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea better use directly `$_GET` or `$_POST` and please remember to check the values you get from the user. Now your code is open for blind sql injections.

Try this code if you don't want to use the recomended mysqli:

```
$lat2 = floatval($_POST['lat']);
$lng2 = floatval($_POST['lng']);
```

If this still not work try dumping your inputs with this two lines:

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Shouldn't they be `floatval`?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky well true, in my last case I stored the lat lon as int so I wrote `intval` by my own practice.