# Is there a PHP variable which includes the merge of $_GET and $_POST?

Tags: php

$_REQUEST includes cookies which I do NOT want in my form posts.

Comment: Change `variables_order` in your php.ini to suit your needs. You can then safely doom your code to rely on proper input to `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @Linus Kleen That doesn't answer the question at all, despite being related to `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @coreyward It kind of hints at the assumption that `$_REQUEST` contains all GPC, though. Also, answer the following: *"I need the result of `9 / 3`. Division is prone to divide by zero errors, which I do NOT want in my code."*

Comment: @Linus Nice edit. Be clear in your answers — chances are someone asking a question isn't going to pick up on a slight hint.

Comment: @Linus Kleen Pffft, that's easy: just subtract a bunch of times.

Answer (score 11):

[The php.ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) responsible for what is in $_REQUEST is `variables_order`

```
Default: variables_order "EGPCS"
```

Change that in your php.ini to:

```
GP
```

for it to include only $_GET and $_POST

### Maybe you don't want to do that

Usually in a web application you use $_GET values to select what to show and $_POST values to transmit what there is to change in a webpage (or user actions that change state in general). Generally it's not advisable to mix those :)

Also that answers explains it quite nice: [When and why should $_REQUEST be used instead of $_GET / $_POST / $_COOKIE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107683/when-and-why-should-request-be-used-instead-of-get-post-cookie/107737#107737)

Or maybe read this: [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request/2143042#2143042)

Also thanks for the comment mario :)

Comment: +1 ... I didn't up-vote before because I don't like this sort of "clever" solution, but with the addition (and emphasis), I believe it's deserving.

Comment: `variables_order` was only ever intended for changing the order. If unset to `GP` it will lead to an empty $_SERVER and $_COOKIE array. Hencewhy PHP 5.3 introduced `request_order` which specifically only affects $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 3):

```
$new_array = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change what `$_REQUEST` holds by looking into the php.ini setting `variables_order`.  Start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `$_REQUEST` for exactly that reason. Access `$_GET`, `$_POST` and friends for their dedicated purposes instead of using `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
$_REQUEST = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
```

Which has the benefit of explicitly listing the order you'd like so you don't override something you didn't expect because the REQUEST order was off.

Answer (score 2):

I would be explicit.

If a GET/POST merge is required in some context, then apply it then -- but I would avoid a blatant clobber. This merge can be easily done per-item and hidden behind a nice, tidy and default-applying wrapper -- perhaps even with a sanitizing/coversion layer right then and there.

No magic required. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, they are all helpful.  The best is to do an array_merge($_GET, $_POST);