# Pass an id with mysql_insert_id() of a .php to another .php

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I am trying to create a variable with one id of the last insert that I do and I am trying to past it to another page.

In the first page this is code:

```
$insert= "INSERT INTO resources (name,description,place,time) VALUES ('$name','$description','$place',CURDATE())";
        mysql_query($insert);
        $last_id= mysql_insert_id();
        header("Location:new_page.php?last_id=$last_id");
```

And in the second page this is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "This is id of resource : $last_id";
?>
```

I can't do to work it, any solution?

Thanks!

Regards

Comment: $_SESSION variables will help you out of it. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: To access last_id from the URL new_page.php?last_id=$last_id you have to use the variable $_GET['last_id']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass variable through more pages like this.

You need to write it using $_GET, because it's in URL.

```
echo $_GET['last_id'];
```

If you want to work with it later, use `SESSION` or `COOKIE`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.
I have tryed it and I have received this error:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
How can I solve it?

Comment: @WhiteShadow: and your code which returns this error is?

Comment: Finally I can solve it with echo "This is id of resource" . $_GET['last_id']

Thanks for your help!!

Regards

Comment: @WhiteShadow: before you forget probably `.` between two strings or any similar typo. If this answer helped you, please answer it as accepted for future readers.

Comment: No, I don't forget it, I have all in a only string and this was the problem.
I have accept this answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve the information from the $_GET data, it won't be a variable automatically.

```
<?php
    echo "This is id of resource : " . $_GET['last_id'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.
I have tryed it and I have received this error:
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
How can I solve it?

Comment: Finally I can solve it with echo "This is id of resource" . $_GET['last_id']

Thanks for your help!!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can also use $_REQUEST['last_id']

```
<?php
    echo "This is id of resource :".$_REQUEST['last_id'];
?>
```

In this way you can access both get and post method variable

Comment: Using $_REQUEST when you don't absolutely have to isn't a good habit to get into. [When and why should $_REQUEST be used instead of $_GET / $_POST / $_COOKIE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107683/when-and-why-should-request-be-used-instead-of-get-post-cookie)

Comment: yeah i know that but i just say this is one of method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, finally I can solve it using $_GET